# Issues when reload numpy module

Tags: python

I use a software (CellProfiler) that start his own python (not the one i install).
We can add our own module in the software, they will be load at the begining.
The version of numpy in this python is 1.5 and i need to use a version of numpy >= 1.6.

I have numpy's sources in this folder:
`E:\\Users\\Nicolas\\CellProfiler Plugin\\site-package\\numpy`

I add the path in sys.path like this.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'E:\\Users\\Nicolas\\CellProfiler Plugin\\site-package')
```

I import numpy like this. But he is already load, and it is the wrong version. So i reload.

```
import numpy as np
np = reload(np)
```

But i've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cellprofiler\modules\__init__.pyc", line 298, in add_module
  File "E:\Users\Nicolas\CellProfiler Plugin\MyModule.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "E:\Users\Nicolas\CellProfiler Plugin\site-package\numpy\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name git_revision
```

the line 128 of `__init__.py` is

```
from version import git_revision as __git_revision__
```

i found that instead of load **version.py** in `E:\Users\Nicolas\CellProfiler Plugin\site-package\numpy\`, he get the one in the library of CellProfiler in this location:

```
C:\Program Files\CellProfiler\library.zip\numpy
```

How can i import numpy 1.7?

Maybe, in other words, how reload all depedences of a module ?